# jquery hide/show hide content when open page

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I'd like the content to be hidden when I first open the page until the button is clicked. Any help?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#rooms").click(function(){
    $("#rooms_box").show();
});
$("#facilities").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
});
 $("events").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
});
 $("#gallery").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
});
 $("#contact").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
});
 $("#search").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use it like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("p , #rooms_box").hide(); // instead of this line you can use the css below
   $("#rooms").click(function(){
     $("#rooms_box").show();
   });
   $("#facilities, #events , #gallery, #contact ,#search").click(function(){
       $("p").show();
  });
});
</script>
```

and its good to use css

```
p , #rooms_box{
   display : none;
}
```

Comment: Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/s3d23jy6/) of this answer.

Comment: @AngelicaKosasih Good Luck :)